# How to use Sonar+JaCoCo to measure line coverage using integration tests (manual+automated)

Tags: integration-testing, code-coverage, sonarqube, jacoco

I am trying to do line coverage analysis of a java based application. Found many resources on the internet on how to use Sonar+JaCoCo plugin to get line coverage results, and it looks very promising. However, I couldn't get a full clarity on how to go about implementing this solution.

More about my project:

1. There is a service being called by a website. The service is java based, and is built using maven.
2. There is also a selenium based test suite that is run on website (which makes calls to the above mentioned service at several instances). The test suite is built & invoked by Ant.
3. The code base for the service and the code base for the tests are at different locations on the same host.
4. I need to generate coverage report for the service based on the integration test suite.

The resources I went through are:

- http://www.sonarsource.org/measure-coverage-by-integration-tests-with-sonar-updated/
- http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html

Even after going through all of these, I am not sure where to put jacoco-agent.jar, whether to make jacoco a part of maven (service's build process) or ant (tests' build process), how to invoke jacoco agent, where to specify the source repository(service's code base) and test repository locations.

I have tried blind permutations of all of the above, but either the maven build or the ant build starts failing as soon as I add jacoco tasks to them.

Can someone please help me out in this? I need to understand the exact steps to follow to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute your server process for the test mode, you need to ensure that jacoco agent is setup on the classpath. The jacoco agent will then effectively listen and record details of the code covered for the life time of the JVM.

You then execute your client side selenium tests which will invoke the server. The jacoco agent in this case will record details of the code executed as part of your tests. When the client test finishes, you need to shutdown your server process which should result in a jacoco coverage file.

The final step is to generate a jacoco html report based on your coverage report. I might suggest you look into moving your ANT based selenium tests into your maven pom, since then it will be easier to control the order of test execution.